# How to get Author details in git and assign them to a variable

Tags: git, devops

I am changing a CI pipeline from mercurail to Git can anyone tell me how to write this in git

```
def command_user = 'hg log -r . --template "{author|user}"'
def command_email = 'hg log -r . --template "{author|email}"'
def command_sign = "hg heads ${env.branch} --template {node}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use placeholders to customize the log output to get the data you're after. Here's an example.

```sh
git log --format=format:"%h | %an | %s"

e9958b9 | George Adams IV | Replace foo with bar.
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats for more placeholders.